# JAVA - Boolean correction - Still going on when pressing Play

Tags: java, boolean

So im pretty close to my end and I can't figure out why its doing like this. Maybe because im stupid right now after coding a while. however. So I have two files that should be allowed to my program. The first one is a MP3 and the Other one is Wav. I got them to work. By that I mean if I choose Wav file, the sound comes, if I choose the mp3 it works so there is no problem with that but the problem is right now is when pressing Open (-> browersing a file) and then press play, the sound should come, and yes it does. so when I open a another file for exemple a new song. then press play. the song is playing with the first song which makes it two tracks at the same time and I want it to make -> when one song is playing then play. and if I choose new song and press play, then the first song should go away. I think im pretty close but yeah. However I have done this

```
static boolean status = true;

btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (e.getSource() == btnPlay) {

                    if(!status) {
                        clip.start();
                        lblPlaying.setText("Enjoy the music!");

                    } else if(status == true) {
                        mp3_player.play();
                        lblPlaying.setText("Enjoy the music!");
                    }
                }
            }

        }); 

public void Choose() throws IOException {

        String userDir = System.getProperty("user.home"); 
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(userDir +"/Desktop");

        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
            String ext = selectedFile.getPath();   



            if(ext.endsWith(".mp3")) { // For mp3
                status = true;
                mp3_player =  new MP3Player(selectedFile);
                lblPlayURL.setText(selectedFile.getName());


            }
            else if(ext.endsWith(".wav")) {
                status = false; //For .Wav

                try {
                    AudioInputStream stream;
                    AudioFormat format;
                    DataLine.Info info;
                    clip = clip;

                    stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(selectedFile);
                    format = stream.getFormat();
                    info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
                    clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                    clip.open(stream);
                    lblPlayURL.setText(selectedFile.getName());


                }


                catch(Exception e) {
                    //whatevers
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

To make the story shorter so what I have done is I have a variable that is set boolean to false. so whenever False is running it takes the Wav. when True its mp3. but as I said. the problem is sitting when.

1. Choose a song
2. Press play for the song
3. Choose new song
4. Press play for the new song (and here is where the 1st one song still going on which I don't want to)

Have I done something wrong with booleans?

EDIT: Forgot to add the open button:

```
btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == btnOpen) {
                    try {
                        Choose();

                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            }
        });
    }
```

edit : Stop method
,

```
btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource() == btnStop) {

                    if(!status) {
                        clip.stop();
                        lblPlaying.setText("Nothing plays right now!");

                    } else if(status == true) {
                        mp3_player.stop();
                        lblPlaying.setText("Nothing plays right now!");
                    }



                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have another flag which tells you if it's playing or not.  Then before you start the song, check the flag, then STOP any music if it's true, then start the new one.

You essentially have a design flaw.  The system is capable of playing multiple songs at once, it didn't know you wanted to stop one of them.

Comment: Do you mean something like this. I create a new boolean status2 = false: then side the Play button I change the status to status2 = true; and then should it work? Im really kinda confused right now haha

Comment: Just saw your edit. hmm. In that case. how can I fix it? or could you explain more

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API you are using, if it's javafx, it has the MediaPlayer.play() and MediaPlayer.stop() to do what you need.

Comment: Well! I do have a method that has a Stop, It works if I press stop. but what If I instead of pressing Stop and choose a new song instead by pressing open and then playing a new song, there is the issue. so I guess the issue is sitting on the ButtonOpen method? like if I make it (If open the filechooser. make the songs stops) ?

Comment: But as I said, I think I have done the Boolean values wrong which causing everything wrong

Comment: Before you choose a new song, programmatically stop the song.  Place the same code in your stop-button action here.

Comment: put everything in the action performed() section at the beginning of your method where you choose a new song.

Comment: Because right now. I have three buttons. One that Open - Which connects to Choose() method. then I have Stop - that stops the song which works aswell. - Then I have play that Plays that song. the only issue is when I skip the part Stop and direclty press the Open once the music is on. then it will multiply the music. If you get it :)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94859/discussion-between-ergonaut-and-thrillofit123).